# How can I look at Prisma.io DB hosted logs

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a prisma.io instance where I have a local graphql server, and a remote DB (hosted at prisma.io). I am getting an error on a request with an id and a message stating 

`[GraphQL error]: Message: Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID:`

I try to run `prisma logs` but receive `The logs command has been replaced by the cluster logs command.`.
I try running `prisma cluster logs` and receive `As mentioned in Prisma 1.7 release notes: https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/releases/tag/1.7.0`. Now I am not sure how to review server logs.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to get your Prisma container name by running `docker ps`.

Generally, there will be two Prisma related containers one for the database (MySQL or Postgres currently, and soon MongoDB) and the other for Prisma GraphQL Engine.

You can look up the name of Prisma GraphQL engine container and then run the following command to get the logs:-

`docker logs <prisma-container-name>`